# putting a char array in allocated space

Tags: c, arrays, char

let's say I did allocate place for an array of 3 chars using

> int *addr = malloc(3 * 1024);

now I got place in memory for the array, how can I after that create the array that it goes to that allocated space?

thank's in advance

Comment: `how can I after that create the array` ???

Comment: You don't "create" an array in C, just use the allocated space for storage.

Comment: `addr[x]=42;` But your array isn't size 3, and isn't `char`s.

Comment: Are you trying to allocate 3 chars, 3 ints, 1024 chars, 1024 ints, or something else...?

Comment: i need char arr[3]; this array (it has 3 chars -> 3 kB) for example to be put in the allocated space

Comment: If you need `arr[3]` then why allocating space for `3*1024`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *addr = malloc(3 * 1024);
```

is not allocating space for `3` `char`s. 
The correct way is

```
char *addr = malloc(3);
```

Now you can put a `char` in the allocated space either by

```
addr[index] = 'c';  // here c stands for a char
```

or by

```
*addr = 'c';
```